# How many discs necessary to cover a big circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Let be a circle a radius **R**,and other discs of radius **r**,palpable.

I can cover the circle,completly, with a minimum number of discs,**N**.I can't cut any disc.

What is the value of **N**,according to **R** and **r**?

Comment: This is [the disk covering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem). Also  see [a precedent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25765/how-many-circles-to-cover-2-times-bigger-circle?rq=1).

Comment: So,where is N=f(R;r)?

Comment: For example, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html).